# What's the difference between a neural network architecture and a neural network model?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, definition

I want to know what's the difference betweens the terms `architecture` and `model` in the context of neural networks?

I think the architecture is the whole definition of the neural net including the hyper-parameters($H$) (e.g. learning rate, dropout, batch size, etc), the parameters($\theta$) (e.g. weight and biases), the feature extraction process, the shape(meaning depth, how many units are and how they are connected) without any specific values for the parameters($\theta$) and hyper-parameters($H$). So it is something like $F(f(x;\theta); H)$ and $F$ is the learning algorithm that help finding good values for $\theta$ that defines $f$.

On the other side I think a neural network model is the same but with specific values for hyper-parameters (like learning rate=0.8, etc) **BUT** without the weights, and biases yet defined, like having the family of functions $f(x;\theta)$

Or is the model just the function $f$ ? in $y = f(x)$ with all the parameters $\theta$ already defined.

How wrong am I ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This terminology is often abused, but the pedantic view is:

- A *model* would be a network architecture with all it's weights viewed as free parameters.
- A *fit model* is a network with fixed weights determined by running a fitting algorithm with some training data.
- *Parameters* map out the various specific shapes that the model can obtain, fitting chooses specific values of the weights that best reflect the training data.
- *Hyperparameters* control the behaviour of the fitting algorithm, they are often set to find the parameters that offer the best performance according to some estimate of hold-out error.

I settled on this terminology after reading [Wasserman's All of Statistics](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~larry/all-of-statistics/).

It's very common to call the *fit model* just a *model*.  I try to use my words precisely and consistently, especially when talking to students, but it is hard to avoid sometimes!

Comment: Have you heard *model* vs. *fit model* "in the wild"? I would typically use architecture to distinguish model *family* from *instance*, I guess.

Comment: Depends on your definition of wild, this is wasserman's definition of a statistical model (a family of random variables, indexed by some parameters).  In the wild, people tend not to distinguish, informally they say both "I fit a linear model", and "I delivered my model to the production team".  I still think the distinction is useful.